# How can we identify the line number in a file matching a particular keyword or a string in terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, terminal, sh

For example, let's say:

I have a file **text.txt**, in which I have the following lines of code:

```
void func()
{
   ordinaryStuff();
   extraordinaryStuff();
   //a comment whoo!
}
```

Now with a **terminal command**, how can i identify on which line i have written

- ordinaryStuff();
- extraordinaryStuff(); or
- added a comment?

> P.S. It does not necessarily has to be a one liner, but it would be nice if it is
>
> > && works too to convert many commands into one liners, but i am looking for an actual one liner

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep '[a-z]*Stuff(' --line-number text.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i further used a delimiter to just get the numeric values!

grep '[a-z]*ex' --line-number text.txt | cut -d ":" -f1

this just returns 

4

Comment: @Pranshu the same with sed but i get 3 4 ? sed -n '/[a-z]*Stuff(/=' text.txt

Comment: @ctac_, if you search for *Stuff, you will get 3 and 4.  Look at the OPs "code", Stuff appears on both 3 and 4.

Comment: @ctac_ in my comment, i have used *ex as the identifier for the RE which is only on line 4, in the example it is Stuff which is on both line 3 and 4